# Tensorflow-text does not import

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import tensorflow text into google colab, but it is not working.
I first used the cell

```
!pip install tensorflow-text
```

and got a message saying that it had been installed correctly, however when I run the cell:

```
import tensorflow_text as text
```

I get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_text as text

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

How do i solve this? I cannot understand why colab does not register it as a library. I have also tried re-hosting the session on my computer and installing tf text on there, but it still gives the module not found error. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Yep, i restarted it repeatedly. First when it didnt work i just downloaded the library onto the computer and reconnected, then i tried to do the same thing again and it still wouldnt work.

Comment: `!pip install tensorflow-text` and then `import tensorflow_text as tft` works for me in Colab.

Comment: It might be different because it is hosted on my own pc instead of the google servers, because i have the exact same code

Comment: I also just tried to uninstall then reinstall tensorflow text and restart the runtime but still no change

Comment: Please check the `TensorFlow` version in your `Google Colab`. There could be version conflicts. It shows TF 2.8.2 initially. If I install `Tensorflow-text` using `!pip install tensorflow-text` then after restarting the kernel,TensorFlow will get upgraded to 2.9.1 and Tensorflow_text version is 2.9.0. Also I am able to successfully `import tensorflow_text as text` without any error after that. Could you please try again and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have multiple python environments installed? You might be installing the package in a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. I had two issues first I overlooked that one small line at the very top, above the imports, of the [Tensorflow code example](https://tfhub.dev/google/experts/bert/pubmed/2). Silly mistake, but it happens... Second, it appears Google Colab currently has some compatibility issues with certain versions of tensorflow-text. I resolved that issue by requiring it to load v2.8.

**Solution:** Install tensorflow-text version 2.8

```
!pip3 install --quiet "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"
```

Comment: But op says they installed the package with a similar command

Comment: You're right @jkr, my apologies. I was working off memory and forgot the more important part with the versioning. I updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [this TensorFlow image on GitHub](https://github.com/sun1638650145/Libraries-and-Extensions-for-TensorFlow-for-Apple-Silicon/releases). Search for a file named: `tensorflow_text`.